# How to properly enable httpd with rcctl on OpenBSD so that it starts automatically?

Tags: openbsd, daemon, rc

On a OpenBSD machine running OpenBSD 6.2 amd64, httpd cannot be started by using rcctl:

```
# rcctl start httpd
httpd(failed)
```

However, when started by just entering `httpd`, it works; but this is not the way to go, I guess. `/var/log/messages` does not contain any hints, nor does any other file in `/var/log/`.

My `/etc/httpd.conf` is rather simple:

```
server "default" {
        listen on * port 80
}
```

`/var/www` exists and `/var/www/htdocs` contains files which are served when started manually. Specifying "root" in `/etc/httpd.conf` had no effect.

How can I get `httpd` to be enabled/started automatically by `rcctl`?

Comment: Any messages in `/var/log/daemon` or other logfiles?

Comment: @Kusalananda Thank for pointing that out; I have added this information in my question. I looked at all files in /var/log/ that have been recently modified and none of them contained any information belonging httpd.

Comment: Are you starting it chrooted or not? What does /etc/rc.conf.local say about flags to httpd?

Comment: How can I determine whether it is being started chrooted? In /etc/rc.conf there's just an entry "httpd_flags=YES".

Comment: Well, that could be the reason the server won't start. The `httpd_flags` variable should be "not `NO`", i.e. setting it to empty will enable the server.  Did you modify the `/etc/rc.conf.local` file manually, or did you do `rcctl enable httpd`?

Comment: And that actually was the reason. I changed that to "httpd_flags=" and now it can be started. I changed the "NO" to "YES" because "rcctl enable" did not work first. However, now even rcctl enable/disable works and I can start and stop httpd using rcctl. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 8):

Your issue was that the `httpd` daemon was given an invalid command line argument ([the string `YES`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/417696/how-to-properly-enable-httpd-with-rcctl-on-openbsd-so-that-it-starts-automatical/417928#comment750230_417696)) when started using `rcctl` and therefore would not start properly.

---

The only "special" value for the `XXX_flags` variables in `/etc/rc.conf.local` is the two letter string `NO`, which disables the corresponding service. This is the default value for most of OpenBSD's services (see `/etc/rc.conf`, which you should *never* modify).

A service is enabled using `rcctl` as root with e.g.

```
# rcctl enable httpd
```

In the case of `httpd`, this will write the line

```
httpd_flags=
```

into `/etc/rc.conf.local`, which will enable the `httpd` service.

The value of `httpd_flags` will be passed to the actual `httpd` daemon upon starting it. You could for example make it read an alternative configuration file with

```
httpd_flags=-f /etc/httpd.conf.local
```

`rcctl` can be used to modify `/etc/rc.conf.local` like this:

```
# rcctl set httpd flags -f /etc/httpd.conf.local
```

It's preferable to use `rcctl` over doing modifications to `/etc/rc.conf.local` directly with an editor.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference of others who may have similar problems, the easiest way to get a log from rcctl is to do `rcctl -d start httpd`, that will at least help with diagnosing the issue.

Answer (score -2):

As Kusalananda pointed out, /etc/rc.conf must contain

```
httpd_flags=NO
```

and /etc/rc.conf.local contains either

```
httpd_flags=
```

to enable httpd or nothing belonging httpd to let it disabled.